# Cant listen to events from iframe with a different domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, addeventlistener, postmessage

I created a page (http://slots.trioland.com/slots/ironman/) that includes an iframe with src on a different domain, which after a minute or 2 redirects me to another page.
I am trying to avoid the redirection by listening to the event messages from the source inside the iframe:

[image: postMessage event]

Therefore,I created the following code to catch the message:

```
function slotslibrequest(event){
  if (event.origin !== "http://slotslib.com")
    return;
  event.source.postMessage($('.flash.flash-inner').width(),
                           event.origin);
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
 // For standards-compliant web browsers
window.addEventListener("message", slotslibrequest, false);
}
else {
 window.attachEvent("onmessage", slotslibrequest);
}
```

The problem is that the listener that I created is not being able to listen to the postMessage from the iframe. Anyone knows where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Is this possible?

I am regretful to say "No". iframes are considered (by the browser engine) as a different DOM document. You need to manage this in the inner iframe application.

Comment: you mean that I should just place the script between <iframe></iframe>?

Comment: I added also:
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.addEventListener("message", slotslibrequest, false);